# Is there a way to access and update the unicode timezone info of JVMs programmatically

Tags: java, unicode, timezone

Each JVM, and in the case of icu4j, a library, has unicode timezone information that is normally updated by a proprietary tool. Is there a (preferably open source) library that can update all of the JVMs of any vendor and other libraries like icu4j programmatically? Failing that, are there any non-programmatic solutions like a script that allows one to access and update this timezone data without using a proprietary tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are asking for one (or both) of these utilities:

- [ICU4J Time Zone Update Utility](http://icu-project.org/download/icutzu.html)
- [Oracle JVM Time Zone Updater Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html)

If neither of these are what you are looking for, please edit your question to be more specific about exactly what you are attempting to do.